# VSO on premise build controller on Azure build not queued

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops

I followed these two articles

http://myalmblog.com/2014/04/configuring-on-premises-build-server-for-visual-studio-online/

http://www.4tecture.ch/blog/custom-build-controller-and-agent-for-visual-studio-online

and created an on premise build controller. I am able to do all of it but when I queue a build from Team Explorer, the build shows "Just Started" and the details has no logs and sits at "Running for 0 seconds". The build does not complete, show any logs or get started (as I am able to stop the build).

My source is in VSO, my build controller is on a VM in Azure.

Answer (score 1):

If this is still not working for you, I'd suggest opening a support case (it's free) to get to the bottom of it. At http://www.visualstudio.com/support-overview-vs, click the Visual Studio Online tile in the “3. Answer wasn’t there? Talk to us” section.

Comment: Turned out to be a permissions issue. It is fixed now. I will update with my answer and all the permissions that will be needed for the vso user that will be used to pull down the source. Someone else might benefit from it.

Comment: Glad to hear you have it sorted out!